# Task Scheduling seems different when debugger is attached

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

We have a WPF software which makes use quite a lot of the “async await” pattern in order to not block the UI thread.

For instance, we use this pattern when opening a file: The UI shows a spinner while in the background we do some IO loading operation and start tasks for long calculations (which should not stop the loading)

What seems to happen is that my loading task is effectively launched on another thread, thus not blocking the UI. So that works.
However, the loading task seems to run synchronously all the other tasks I create, such as long calculation which the loading does not need.

I pinpoint the debugger because:

- I noticed that for big files, when the debugger is attached, the spinner runs longer for about 10-20 times.
- Running release or debug version does not affect behavior.
- As long as the debugger is attached, it is way slower.
- Detaching the debugger in the middle of the loading will run super fast right afterwards.

I know this only because when breaking with the debugger, I see:

- On the current thread, the top of the call stack is my “LoadProjectAsync”,
- That thread is currently in the code of the long calculations, which have been triggered by “async void” (since we don't care about them immediately and thus shouldn't be run synchronously)
- The “Tasks” window in Visual Studio always show 1 "Active" task, and some other tasks which are always in the “Complete” status. Never saw two tasks active in this session.

Here’s a little the code layout (this is a simplified version to give you an idea of the flow)
By clicking on a button, the UI calls a LoadProjectFile method, which looks like the following:

```
public async void LoadProjectFile(string path)
{
    ShowSpinner = true;

    var projectFileModel = await ProjectManager.LoadProjectAsync(path)

    //… do more stuff here. This work fine and shouldn't be related to the problem

    ShowSpinner = false;
}

public class ProjectManager
{
    public Task<ProjectModel> LoadProjectAsync(string filePath)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => LoadProject(filePath));
    }

    public ProjectModel LoadProject(string filePath)
    {
        //Opens file                  
        var model = new ProjectModel(filePath);

        DoSomeComputations(model);

        return model;
    }

    public async void DoSomeComputations()
    {            
        //Computations are made here using "await".
        //They seem to run synchronously and 
        //block the LoadProject function, 
        //which does not require at all these results.
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Sadly, if I make a project with simplified code, it runs perfectly with a debugger attached and will not show the symptoms I'm describing.

I understand that a new task does not mean a new thread, but that shouldn't be the reason why in this case.

I would like to understand why the scheduling is different (or whatever else that is happening) and what could I do about it?

Comment: Yes. Don't measure performance of code that is being debugged :)... To try to pinpoint slowness - look at debug output - maybe you spot some excessive loging/exceptions/something...

Comment: I know this is your "minimized" sample code, so this may be a symptom of that, but `DoSomeComputations(model);` is not correct. It should be awaited.

Comment: which part is calling `LoadProjectFile(string path)`

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set?  If so, try clearing them to eliminate that as a suspect.  Also, it could be related to loading symbols (you could turn off symbol loading to eliminate that suspect).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Debug output is sadly irrelevant since in Release build I do get the same effect (and there is no `Trace.WriteLine` neither).  I tried anyway, and it did not have an effect.

Comment: @Alex: DoSomeComputations(model) is valid.  You can call an `async void` function without awaiting for it.  In my real code, it is an event handler which is called, which is an `async void`.

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml: The `LoadProjectFile(string path)` is called by a Command, bound to a button in xaml

Comment: @MattSmith No breakpoints, and disabled the symbols.  Good idea for the breakpoints, I sometimes have conditional ones and others which maybe could have been the culprits.